# Inequality: $\sum_{k=1}^{n^3} \frac{1}{k^{\frac{2}{3}}}<3n$

Tags: inequality

I tried by induction, Jensen, comparing, but no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the monotonicity of the function $x\mapsto x^{-2/3}$ you can write:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n^3}k^{-2/3}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n^3}k^{-2/3}<1+\int_1^{n^3}x^{-2/3}dx=1+3n-3=3n-2<3n$$